# How to change param in url with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

i have list tag li

```
<li data-src="http://localhost/project/?coupon=asKSawe&type=1"></li>
<li data-src="http://localhost/project/?coupon=adTeLw&type=1"></li>
<li class="item-li" data-src="http://localhost/project/?coupon=12Dffr&type=1"></li>
<li class="item-li" data-src="http://localhost/project/?coupon=dldpOO2&type=1"></li>
<li class="item-li" data-src="http://localhost/project/?coupon=MMok231&type=1"></li>
<li data-src="http://localhost/project/?coupon=xC41k23&type=1"></li>
```

how to use preg_replace to change coupon to strtoupper, with only coupon, result i hope

```
<li data-src="http://localhost/project/?coupon=ASKSAWE&type=1"></li>
<li data-src="http://localhost/project/?coupon=ADTELW&type=1"></li>
<li class="item-li" data-src="http://localhost/project/?coupon=12DFFR&type=1"></li>
<li class="item-li" data-src="http://localhost/project/?coupon=DLDPOO2&type=1"></li>
<li class="item-li" data-src="http://localhost/project/?coupon=MMOK231&type=1"></li>
<li data-src="http://localhost/project/?coupon=xC41K23&type=1"></li>
```

thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the context of this HTML, are you in control of its generation, or are you scraping it from somewhere? Where do these URL's come from in the first place?

Comment: You should try using [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Comment: this html is result export from code php. how to t recieve result from preg_replace, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with preg_replace_callback:

```php
<?php

$test = <<<EOD
<li data-src="http://localhost/project/?coupon=asKSawe&type=1"></li>
<li data-src="http://localhost/project/?coupon=adTeLw&type=1"></li>
<li class="item-li" data-src="http://localhost/project/?coupon=12Dffr&type=1"></li>
<li class="item-li" data-src="http://localhost/project/?coupon=dldpOO2&type=1"></li>
<li class="item-li" data-src="http://localhost/project/?coupon=MMok231&type=1"></li>
<li data-src="http://localhost/project/?coupon=xC41k23&type=1"></li>
EOD;

$result = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\?coupon=([^&]*)/',
    function ($x) {
        return "?coupon=".strtoupper($x[1]);
    },
    $test
);

print($result)
?>
```